# R read only specific row of textfile and store them in data.frame

Tags: r, sed, dataframe

I have the following problem. There is a textfile that I want to import into R.
It looks like this:

```
#  Below, those lines that start with a minus sign and an l (-l)
#  define loci, while those that start with a minus sign and an i (-i)
#  define epistatic interactions between the loci previously defined.
#  The loci must be defined before the interactions can be defined.
#  For some experimental designs, some interactions will be ignored.
#   
-start model
#
# Here is the data on the QTLS...
#
-t     3   is the number of traits
#
#
-k     1
# for trait -number     1
#
#      #  ..Chrom..Markr.    .RecombiL.    .RecombiR.    .Additive.    .Dominance
-l     1      2     19         0.0823        0.0028        1.1712        0.0000
#
#   QTL1   QTL2   Type       Value  
#
#
#
-k     1
# for trait -number     2
#
#      #  ..Chrom..Markr.    .RecombiL.    .RecombiR.    .Additive.    .Dominance
-l     1      2     14         0.0309        0.0564        0.4635        0.0000
#
#   QTL1   QTL2   Type       Value  
#
#
#
-k     1
# for trait -number     3
#
#      #  ..Chrom..Markr.    .RecombiL.    .RecombiR.    .Additive.    .Dominance
-l     1     15     61         0.0782        0.0261        0.1200        0.0000
#
#   QTL1   QTL2   Type       Value  
#
#
#
#End of this block of information
#
-end model
#
```

Now I want to read the rows that begins with -l and save them in a data.frame.
Does anybody know a way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: While I'm sure that this is possible in R, you might find that a solution using a tool like sed is much nicer. One simple way to expand your inquiry would be to add the sed tag to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datL <- readLines(textConnection("#  -start model
#
# Here is the data on the QTLS...
#
-t     3   is the number of traits
#
#
-k     1
# for trait -number     1
#
#      #  ..Chrom..Markr.    .RecombiL.    .RecombiR.    .Additive.    .Dominance
-l     1      2     19         0.0823        0.0028        1.1712        0.0000
#
#   QTL1   QTL2   Type       Value  
#
#
#
-k     1
# for trait -number     2
#
#      #  ..Chrom..Markr.    .RecombiL.    .RecombiR.    .Additive.    .Dominance
-l     1      2     14         0.0309        0.0564        0.4635        0.0000
#
#   QTL1   QTL2   Type       Value  
#
#
#
-k     1
# for trait -number     3
#
#      #  ..Chrom..Markr.    .RecombiL.    .RecombiR.    .Additive.    .Dominance
-l     1     15     61         0.0782        0.0261        0.1200        0.0000
#
#   QTL1   QTL2   Type       Value  
#
#
#
#End of this block of information
#
-end model
#"))
```

Now the code:

```
> goodL <- grepl("^.l", datL)
> datL[goodL]
[1] "-l     1      2     19         0.0823        0.0028        1.1712        0.0000"
[2] "-l     1      2     14         0.0309        0.0564        0.4635        0.0000"
[3] "-l     1     15     61         0.0782        0.0261        0.1200        0.0000"


> read.table(text=datL[goodL])[ ,-1]
  V2 V3 V4     V5     V6     V7 V8
1  1  2 19 0.0823 0.0028 1.1712  0
2  1  2 14 0.0309 0.0564 0.4635  0
3  1 15 61 0.0782 0.0261 0.1200  0
```

The two or three tricks are constructing a logical index to pick only the lines that have the 'l' in the second position and then passing just the "good stuff" to `read.table` as a character vector and removing the extraneous column of "-l"'s.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Is it possible to directly import the file into textConnection??

Comment: I used `textConnection('text')` which returns a 'connection' that `read.table` can use as a file object, but presumably you would substitute a valid quoted path and filename or build a valid file with the `file.path` function to refer to a text file on your drive. You can use `readLines(...)` with a file argument.

Comment: I think you could use a file() call to establish an object, but it would be easier to use readLines().